# TFS: remove packages folder that was already committed

Tags: svn, tfs, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I have a project in VS2015 that the previous dev had committed the '`packages`' folder too.

We are on TFS (not sure which ver, likely 2010..?) and if I just delete the folder from the source control explorer I cannot compile because it doesn't restore the packages.

I am guessing it's because I manually deleted it? I rolled back so it's compiling again, but I'd like to know for future ref how to remove an existing `packages` folder from an already committed solution.

(I know about the .tfignore file and have put one in place for future commits. Now, how to remove the existing packages folder and still compile?)

Comment: That doesn't seem right, build process does not care how source control handles files? Perhaps the rollback left an empty packages folder, whereas delete removed it altogether - causing the restore to fail?

Answer (score 0):

**Its not recommend to check packages folder in source control.** NuGet supports automatic package restore, which automatically restores packages on build.

Here is doc for migrating to this model: http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/migrating-to-automatic-package-restore.

And this can save you a lot of hassle with checked-in packages folder.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I know this. My question was, however, how to remove the packages folder when it is ALREADY committed.

Answer (score 0):

The way to delete the committed packages is simple: Just delete the whole "packages" folder.

The issue you have is that the nuget package isn't been restored during the build. Auto package restore is available from TFS2013. So you need to check the TFS version you are using. If it is older then TFS2013, you need to update your project to restore the packages before build. Refer to this link for details: [Package Restore with Team Foundation Build](https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-restore/team-build)

Comment: I did try that as I mentioned in my first post in this thread. we are on TFS 2013 too.

Comment: @Beau Can you share the error log after removing the packages folder?